# Why is Schema Validation for Mule App xml failing for Java Component Binding?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I've configured the following component binding in my mule app.

```
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="activityController"/>
            <binding interface="edu.ucdavis.edustream.esb.activity.service.EduStreamService" method="putActivity">
                <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                        path="putActivity" />
            </binding>
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
```

It builds and runs without error, but the mule xml lists the following errors:

```
Element: Binding Properties is not allowed to be child of element Java
Element: VM is not allowed to be child of element Binding Properties
```

My config is very similar to that found in the following blog and accompanying github src:

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-component-bindings/
https://github.com/mulesoft/blog/tree/master/StockStats

Any ideas why the mule app xml schema validation is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem in the MuleStudio validation itself, which lacks the support for bindings still. You can ignore that for the time being until it gets fixed.

Comment: This is still an issue in 3.6.  Do you happen to know if there any plan to make this kind of component binding valid in AnyPoint Studio in the future?